# CDF of the difference of two iid random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two iid random variables with cdf $F$. Then, it is easy to calculate the cdf $G$ of their difference:
$$G(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x + y) \mathrm{d}F(y).$$

But suppose we know $G$, can we have a formula for $F$?

Comment: No: given $G$, if $F(x)$ satisfies your equation, so will $F(x+c)$, for any fixed $c$. That is, the distribution of $(X+c)-(Y+c)$ is the same as that of $X-Y$.

Comment: There are other interesting situations where $F$ cannot be determined from $G$. Feller's book (Vol II) constructs two real valued different characteristic functions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ such that  $|\phi_1|=|\phi_2|$. If $\{X,Y\}$ and$\{U,V\}$ are i.i.d. with the these characteristic functions  then $X-Y \stackrel d{=} {U-V}$.